# Array is not showing last element in the output

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project where there are 2 databases (firestore) at same level.

One having user's profile and other has list of schedules.

**Profile Db** - user's email *(stored as an array in the Db)* , name, age.

**Dates Db** - user's email, time and date of schedule.

The function below matches user's email from the profile db with every email given in dates db and gives the list of dates having the same email.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

startDateArr pushes the date records from dates Db so that the last date can be filtered and user can be informed of the last schedule.

**ISSUE**

I am unable to find the last date that is stored of the array.

```
let startDateArr = [];

db.collection('dates').onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    db.collection('profiles').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((profileDoc) => {
        if (profileDoc.data().userEmail[profileDoc.data().userEmail.length - 1] === doc.data().userEmail) {
          let finalDate = `${ doc.data().startDate[ doc.data().startDate.length - 1 ] } 
                         ${ doc.data().startMonth[ doc.data().startMonth.length - 1 ] }`
          startDateArr.push(finalDate);
        }
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: If you don't need all the data, you could simply sort in descending and take first element. Also, you're using same variable name `querySnapshot` for both your callbacks. That could be an issue too.

Comment: Tried that but it is giving the same output.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your document's from both collection? It might be easier to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Btw: instead of `somearray[somearray.length -1]` you can just use `somearray.at(-1)`

Comment: Your profiledoc has an array of emails? And you are only comparing the last email to the email in your schedule doc? I really don't understand your data model. Can you post some example data?

Comment: We are not getting the whole picture of your db and collections can you share the screenshot of your db with editing the question ?

Comment: As a tertiary look, I think you're going to run into a bigger issue; what if a user changes their email? You would then have to go through the entire database and update every single instance of that email. A much better option is to store the users UID, which is immutable. Then you can simply query the dates db where users `uid = this users uid`, sorted by date, getting the `.last` and you're done.